# trim expects parameter to be string

Tags: php

I get an error saying trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given. It is the second line:

```
        $page_result = $title_result->FetchRow();
        if (strlen(trim($page_result)) > 0)
            $this->body = stripslashes(urldecode($page_result['title_module_text']));
        else
            $this->body = "";
```

I thought the first parameter from trim() IS a string?

Comment: `FetchRow()` probably returns a row, not a string

Comment: Well, if `FetchRow()` is returning an array, it's not a string

Comment: use `$page_result['title_module_text']` instead of `$page_result` inside trim(...

Comment: On line 3 you approach $page_result as an array and at line 2 you're approaching it like a string. Seems pretty obious if you've read the some information on php.net/trim and the class you use for fetching the row data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$page_result = $title_result->FetchRow();
$title_module_text = trim($page_result['title_module_text']);
if (strlen($title_module_text) > 0)
    $this->body = stripslashes(urldecode($title_module_text));
else
    $this->body = "";
```

Answer (score 3):

From the MySQL documentation: `array mysql_fetch_row ( resource $result )`

"Returns a numerical array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead."

Check out http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM people WHERE id = '32'");
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $row[0]; // 32
echo $row[1]; // the name value
?>
```